# MS SQL - How to order results by wildcard?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query:

```
SELECT [Name]
  FROM [dbo].[City]
  where name like '%laus%'
```

Results:

[image]

How to order so records with leading wildcard (3,4) are first?

Comment: You just have to add "order by name" in your query ... it does not make any difference when you use wildcard "order" works same with or without wildcard

Comment: The best way to get a precise result is to use full-text-search. I guess you want to order by the best match of your like expression

Comment: How do you decide that Lausanne and Lausen need to appear first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your may try, but best way use full-text-search

```
SELECT [Name]
  FROM [City]
  where name like '%laus%'
ORDER BY 
    CHARINDEX('laus',name)
```

Comment: why best way use full-text-search ?

Comment: best match sorting

Comment: The same as per comment on Denis answer: This will not display all cities, only city like '%laus%.

Comment: @PawelCz 1. Read TS question. 2. Denis Rubashkin was later, do not you think so?

Comment: @TapakahUa, uhhh, aggressive one, chill out. OP accepted your answer, so I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE(name )
AS
(
SELECT 'Berlin'         UNION ALL
SELECT 'Laura'          UNION ALL
SELECT 'Losangels'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lausanne'       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lausen'         UNION ALL
SELECT 'Roamanel'       UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sankt Niklaus'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Vennes sur-Lausanne'

)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN name like 'Laus%' THEN 1 END ) DESC
```

Result

```
name
--------
Lausanne
Lausen
Losangels
Laura
Roamanel
Sankt Niklaus
Vennes sur-Lausanne
Berlin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @City TABLE(Name VARCHAR(32))

INSERT @City VALUES
('Belmont-sur-Lausanne'),
('Lausanne'),
('Lausen'),
('Le Mont-sur-Lausanne'),
('Berlin')


SELECT [Name]
  FROM @City
  --where name like '%laus%'
  order by CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%laus%', name) = 0
    THEN LEN(name) 
    ELSE PATINDEX('%laus%', name)
    END
    ,name
```

Comment: This will not display all cities, only city like '%laus%. I think OP wants to display all of them. But it is a good try!

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @PawelCz, I've corrected my answer. But, maybe using a big number instead of LEN(name) could be a better decision.